# Observable of HttpClient can not map correctly from HttpResponse

Tags: angular, typescript, httpclient, angular7

I got a service in angular7 what gives me back some keys:

```
  getList(
    pageSize: number = 30,
    pageNumber: number = 0,
    filters: CKeyListFilters = <CKeyListFilters>{},
    sortByKey: string = 'activeTo',
    sortOrder: SortOrder = SortOrder.DESC
  ): Observable<ListPaginated<CKey[]>> {
    // ....

    return this.http
      .get<ListPaginated<CKey[]>>(`${environment.CApiUrl}/Get`, {
        params: params,
        observe: 'response',
      })
      .pipe(
        map((resp: HttpResponse<CKey[]>) => {
          return {
            content: resp.body,
            pagination: this.utilities.getPaginationMetaData(resp),
          } as ListPaginated<CKey[]>;
        }),
        catchError((error) => {
          throw error;
        })
      );
  }
```

But inside the `pipe` method I got this error:

```
error TS2345: Argument of type 'OperatorFunction<HttpResponse<CKey[]>, ListPaginated<CKey[]>>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'OperatorFunction<HttpResponse<ListPaginated<CKey[]>>, ListPaginated<CKey[]>>'.
```

So I want to map the `HttpResponse<CKey[]>` to `ListPaginated<CKey[]>` But I don't know how can I transform it.

I inherited this code and I'm a newbie in `typescript`, so any suggestion is useful for me!

Comment: Could you please provide the line that imports `map`?

Comment: @mbojko sure! Its from `import { catchError, map } from 'rxjs/operators'; `

Comment: Oh. My hypothesis was that the wrong `map` was imported from rxjs. But it appears to be the right one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK. Here it is:

```
      .get<ListPaginated<CKey[]>>(`${environment.CApiUrl}/Get`, {
        params: params,
        observe: 'response',
      })
      .pipe(
        map((resp: HttpResponse<CKey[]>) => {
```

in line 1, the requested resource is of type `ListPaginated<CKey[]>`. In line 6, the `map`'s argument is of type `HttpResponse<CKey[]>`. Those types must match (or alternatively you can remove `resp`'s typing from the `map` altogether).

Comment: You are right! :) Thanks. I had to write `.get<CKey[]>(...)`